# Unable to debug an encodded javascript?

Tags: javascript, encoding

I’m having some problems debugging an encoded javacscript. This script I’m referring to given in this link over here.

The encoding here is simple and it works by shifting the unicodes values to whatever Codekey was use during encoding. The code that does the decoding is given here in plain English below:-

```
<script language="javascript">
function dF(s){
var s1=unescape(s.substr(0,s.length-1)); var t='';
for(i=0;i<s1.length;i++)t+=String.fromCharCode(s1.charCodeAt(i)-s.substr(s.length- 1,1));
document.write(unescape(t));
}
</script>
```

I’m interested in knowing or understanding the values (e.g s1,t). Like for example when the value of i=0 what values would the following attributes / method would hold

```
s1.charCodeAt(i) and s.substr(s.length-1,1)
```

The reason I’m doing this is to understand as to how a CodeKey function really works. I don’t see anything in the code above which tells it to decode on the basis of codekey value. The only thing I can point in the encoding text is the last character which is set to 1 , 2 ,3 or 4 depending upon the codekey selected during encoding process. One can verify using the link I have given above.

However, to debug, I’m using firebug addon with the script running as localhost on my wamp server. I’m able to put a breakpoint on the js using firebug but I’m unable to retrieve any of the user defined parameters or functions I mentioned above.

I want to know under this context what would be best way to debug this encoded js.

Comment: Have you tried adding breakpoints in javascript console?

Comment: Use Opera's Dragonfly, it allows you to inspect also dynamically inserted scripts (what `document.write` seems to do).

Comment: Generally: Don't debug encoded code. Develop with the original source, and switch to encoding only in production.

Comment: @everyone. I have been able to decode some of it using a js debugger addon for firefox. Here is the http://s9.postimage.org/iajkdl9fy/scan.jpg screenshot. What I'm unable to understand is how the script get the codekey. If codekey is 2 then unicode is shifted twice how does the code know this. I got no idea how does these characters (&1B&1:&1:&1) also shown in the screenshot appears the encoding was suppose to close at 4F (>). When the codekey is shift to 2 these characters are changed to &2...but how does the script use this information? I don't know

Comment: and beside encoding thing on programing i want to understand how does s1.charCodeAt(i)-s.substr(s.length- 1,1) works in the above script. Charcode returns integer and substr get long strings of words as output . Is it possible to subtract string from integer.?

Comment: @Bergi can i use firefox dragonfly too?

Comment: @LinkmeLld: Never heard that dragonfly is available for FF, too, but it might be possible.

Comment: @Bergi i installed opera and used dragonfly but it seems so difficult to locate the variables of interest? Like s1,t and s

Comment: @LinkmeLld: Sure, for inspecting them you'd have to set breakpoints like in Firebug. I thought you were more interested in the script that `document.write` inserts - you can select it in the scripts panel

Comment: @Bergi thanks this tool did the trick for me:)